# How to seperate integers from strings on list?

Tags: python, python-2.7

I'm currently trying to make a Blackjack game and I've been struggling on counting the total number in hand.

my hand would consist of the cards rank and the cards suit such as:

```
hand = ['C9','S4']
```

I know that you can easily count the number if there's no string there:
e.g:

```
hand = ['9','4']
```

I can easily do:

```
hand = map(int,hand)
```

and then

```
sum(hand)
```

But how am I suppose to do it with the string inside it?
If there's any other good ways to calculate the total other than using my way, feel free to post them.

Comment: you can create a new list with integers from your list hand, and sum it. Just a small for-loop.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If the numerical value is always the part of the string that excludes the first character, then you can achieve that through

```
sum([int(s[1:]) for s in hand])
```

Comment: Hey thanks it works! I'm wondering why can't I do:

for s in hand:
      total = sum(int(s[1:]))
as this would give me a TypeError saying 'int' object is not iterable?

Comment: That is saying that for every `s` in `hand`, Python should try to calculate the sum of a single integer; `sum`, on the other hand, does not know what to do with an `int` but needs something to iterate over. You could make it run by changing it to `total = sum([int(s[1:])])`, but the result will not be what you expect. Can you see why not?

Answer (score 1):

Instead of doing just one `map` you could do two `map`s, one to get the second item (assuming the value you want to sum is the second item):

```
from operator import itemgetter
l = ['C9','S4']
sum(map(int, map(itemgetter(1), l)))
```

However instead of working with strings you could also work with [`collections.namedtuple`](https://docs.python.org/2.7/library/collections.html#collections.namedtuple)s (like a lightweight class around a normal `tuple`):

```
from collections import namedtuple

Card = namedtuple('Card', ['suit', 'rank'])
l = [Card('C', 9), Card('S', 4)]
sum(i.rank for i in l)
```